# Is there a vscode QT widget that can be embedded in an application

Tags: qt, visual-studio-code, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

I am creating a free application with pyqt5.

In this application, i need to give the users the possibility to type custom python scripts.

I don't want to develop a whole python syntax parser and provide autocompletion as it seems a long process and the scripting is not the most important part of the application.

I ask whether vscode (or other script editing tool) offer the possibility to embed a special editor as a QWidget inside an application that provides syntax analysis and autocompletion.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: QScintilla, the Qt port of [scintilla](https://scintilla.org), a library for text editing oriented to source code editing.

This is how you set up a basic editor with minimal syntax highlighting:

```
class Editor(Qsci.QsciScintilla):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        font = self.font()
        font.setFamily('mono')
        self.setFont(font)

        # create a "Lexer", which is what allows syntax highlighting
        # within the editor; the following is the class for python
        # syntax, but there are other classes for different languages
        lexer = Qsci.QsciLexerPython()
        lexer.setDefaultFont(font)
        self.setLexer(lexer)
```

You can find the documentation at the [official site](https://qscintilla.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Is it mandatory to embbed the editor inside your application?
Maybe you could make your app open a system editor instead and let the user choose the tool of his preference.